# NSeviceBus - Performance degradation when endpoints are disconnected

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus3

I'm looking into using NServiceBus for fault tolerant communications between a central server and many remote located PCs.

I'm running the GateWay sample in the newest (3.2) release, and all works well - with a trial commercial license the performance seems great, sending to 3 remote PCs. But - to test the fault tolerance, if I disconnect one of the PCs, I notice that although the other sites continue to receive messages from the server, the performance suffers greatly - the site can be waiting up to 30 seconds to recieve a message - presumably because the server is busy dealing with retries for the site that is disconnected.

Is there a simple configuration-type answer to this?

Comment: Is this the same issue as was asked on the nsb list?

Comment: Hi yes it is. I wouldn't normally cross-post, but after 24 hours I had no response on the nsb list

Comment: No worries just making sure that  you had solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here was that I hadn't specified the number of worker threads on the server. I changed this to 5 worker threads, and the issue has now gone away.